# Spatial correlation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, autocorrelation

I want to do spatial correlation with many variables. In fact when I do correlation densities points results are better than when I work with attributive data. Can I use the result of the density of points in the spatial autocorrelation.

Comment: Spatial Correlation (autocorrelation) is a very broad field. Have you had a look at the Arc help on Global Moran's I, for example? There's a very good primer on this at http://gisgeography.com/spatial-autocorrelation-moran-i-gis/

Answer (score 2):

Spatial Correlation (autocorrelation) is a very broad field.

You could look at the Arc help on Global Moran's I, for example.

There's a very good primer on this at:

http://gisgeography.com/spatial-autocorrelation-moran-i-gis/...

However, if you want to consider *what* attributes may be influencing the clusters - something like Luc Anselin's LISA might be worth considering (if you have University library access you can find lit there - failing that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicators_of_spatial_association)

It's best run in the standalone GeoDa package (available here: https://geodacenter.asu.edu/software) - which is really well documented and uses ESRI files.